# laravel inner join or left join?

Tags: php, laravel

i have a piece of code that is supposed to join two tables Enumerator Data and export the result. Here is the controller code for handling that.

```
 $joinTableName = (new Enumerator())->getTable();
    $fromTableName = (new FarmData())->getTable();

    $selectedColumns = [
        "{$fromTableName}.first_name",
        "{$fromTableName}.middle_name",
        "{$fromTableName}.last_name",
        "{$fromTableName}.farm_phone_number",
        "{$fromTableName}.age",
        "{$fromTableName}.farmer_bvn",
        "{$joinTableName}.state",
        "{$joinTableName}.lga",
        "{$fromTableName}.enum_unique_id"
    ];

    $v2_farm_data = FarmData::whereNotNull('enum_unique_id')->select($selectedColumns)
    ->leftJoin(
        $joinTableName,
        "{$joinTableName}.unique_id",
        '=',
        "{$fromTableName }.enum_unique_id"
    )
    ->get();
```

The resulting csv data has some empty state and lga fields. I presume it has to do with the fact that the Enumerator table has about 20,000 records while the Data table has about 100,000 records. Using just a join statement returns data records of just 20,000. I want to get all the data records which are about 100,000. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Im not sure I follow, whats the issue with the left join you're using now, does that not return all `100,000` rows from the Data table?

Comment: @WesleySmith the leftjoin returns all 100,000 results but only 20,000 of them have valid state and lga fields while the others are null. Using join statement returns only the 20,000 fields but with no null fields

Comment: Thats exactly what i'd expect though. If Data has 100,000 rows, and Enumerator only has 20, 000 rows, then presumably there are 80,000 Data rows that do not have a related Enumerator row.

Comment: @WesleySmith the weird thing is, the 80,000 rows have related Enumerator row. It's literally driving me nuts

Comment: Wait, why does your join call use `joinTableName` for both params?

Comment: @WesleySmith that's a typo. Still gives the same result. Will edit it now

Comment: Can you please show the migration or create statement for both tables?

Comment: Also, can you please try `->leftJoin($joinTableName, "{$fromTableName }.enum_unique_id", '=', "{$joinTableName}.unique_id")`  [per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)